# Flutter fixed widget size on app ignoring device display size setting

Tags: flutter, user-interface, frontend, responsive

I am developing a Flutter app and I have a problem which is my widget size varies based on the device I am using. I manage to fixed the text size by setting the `textScaler` in `main.dart` like below:

```
builder: (context, child) {
    final mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    final scale = mediaQueryData.textScaler
        .clamp(minScaleFactor: 1.0, maxScaleFactor: 1.0);
    return MediaQuery(
        data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
          textScaler: scale,
        ),
        child: child!);
}
```

However, when I changed the display size from my phone setting, every widget in the app will be enlarged and cause some of the widget overflowed / inconsistency in the widget size.

Is there any way to ignore the display size phone setting from the app or any way to make the app more responsive?

Comment: Even setting the minScaleFactor to 1.0 isn’t a good practice. Your app is no longer accessible to people with bad eye sight who want their text to be larger. A better solution would be to write more responsive widgets so that they adapt to every screen size.

Comment: @Andrej can you show me / give an example on how to make my app more responsive?

Comment: how your text change size when max and minimum  scale are same `(minScaleFactor: 1.0, maxScaleFactor: 1.0)`

Comment: Responsiveness doesnt mean that increase the text when its on wider screen. but its more content displayed compare to smaller screen. Yes you may also change the size for some title. But not change all the font size